# Does anyone use websocket instead of gRPC or REST api for intercommunication between microservices?

Tags: websocket, microservices, grpc

Websocket has everything that gRPC does, and is implemented the same way.

So is there any example of such system.

If not why?

Answer (score 14):

[WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) is an older standard part of the [HTML5 Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), whereas gRPC is a complete remote procedure call mechanism. gRPC uses HTTP/2 under the hood.

That said, comparing **gRPC to WebSockets** is a bit like **apple to oranges**.
The HTTP/2 vs WebSockets comparison is more interesting in my opinion. Here is a link to one I like: [Will WebSocket survive HTTP/2?](https://www.infoq.com/articles/websocket-and-http2-coexist)

On top of the bare communication protocol itself, gRPC handles a lot more. It adds the whole RPC layer. You define everything in a proto file, and the statically typed (depends on the language) client and server codes are generated. **HTTP/2 is an implementation detail of gRPC**, and actually, it could be implemented using WebSockets, but WebSockets would not add much on top of bare TCP communication (except for the security layer in case of wss://)

WebSockets was more like a workaround for implementing server push back when it was not available in the HTTP/1.1 protocol, and long polling was the only option.

**Answering the question:** I do not know of any WebSocket based microservice intercommunication framework, but I do use gRPC for this purpose, and it is awesome ;)

Comment: Http/2 works automatically, you don't have to interact with it at application level. For websocket you do. For gRPC, even though it uses HTTP/2, you define events handlers, pub/sub sort of thing. Which is very much like websockets. Given that I'd think it'd be easier to implement contract validation over websocket then to build gRPC.

Comment: gRPC is really simple in my opinion. And a lot less error prone compared to some text based websocket communication. What do you mean by "contract validation"

Comment: websocket handles binary... gRPC requires you to write out input and output in protobuf files, which is good practice as it also serves as documentation between devs. gRPC library enforces this otherwise throw error.

Comment: "websocket handles binary" - of course, HTTP/1.1 also handles binary, but it is not designed to handle binary well. And generally if you want binary communication you are better off with a framework like ProtocolBuffers (with or without gRPC) or thrift

Comment: websocket  has always supported binary, confused about that.